# jquery datetime picker control popup

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using jQuery DateTimePicker plugin from http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/.
I don't want to open the calendar popup when focus on textbox instead of that i want to give some image button at the end of textbox and when user clicks on image button then only calendar popup should open for date time selection.  When focus on textbox user should be able to enter manually. if popup is coming sometimes popup is coming on above textbox so we can't see anything in textbox to enter manually.
sample code is as follows:

```
     $('#StartDate').datetimepicker({
            value: defaultStartDateTime,
            step: 15,
            closeOnDateSelect: true,
            format: 'm/d/Y H:i',
            mask: true }); 
     $('#StartDate').focus(function () {             
            $('#clientLogsStartDate').datetimepicker('hide');                           
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turn off `datetimepicker` events

```
open.xdsoft focusin.xdsoft mousedown.xdsoft touchstart
```

```js
$('#StartDate').datetimepicker({
  value: new Date(),
  step: 15,
  closeOnDateSelect: true,
  format: 'm/d/Y H:i',
  mask: true
}).off('open.xdsoft focusin.xdsoft mousedown.xdsoft touchstart')

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#StartDate').datetimepicker('show')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-DOS9W6NR+NFe1fUhEE0PGKY/fubbUCnOfTje2JMDw3Y=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<input id="StartDate" type="text">
<button>Show</button>
```